# Positive Integer sum showing negative integer

Tags: python

I know how to select positive or negative integers from what the user has inputted.

I have done a code which would identify whether an integer is positive or negative- The main problem is that instead of the negative integer being added to the negative total sum, it is being taken away from the positive integer sum.

Please, could someone help me with this small error?

```
Num = 0
positive_Total = 0
negative_Total = 0
total=0
positive = 0
negative = 0
Sum_Positive=0
Sum_Negative=0

for Num in range(10):
    total+=int(input("Please enter a integer:"))
    if Num >=0:
        Sum_Positive =+total
    if Num < 0:
        Sum_Negative = +total

print("Sum of Positive Integers:"+str(Sum_Positive))
print("Sum of Negative Integers:"+str(Sum_Negative))
```

[image of code in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ywx.png)

Comment: You've indented the second `if` one level too deep.

Comment: What do you expect `Sum_Positive =+total` to do?

Comment: If the inputted value (total) is more than 0 , that it will be added to the sum of positive integers ?

Comment: `=+` is not the same as `+=`.  `a += b` is a shortcut for `a = a + b`, but `a =+ b` just means `a = +b`, i.e. a equals positive b.

Comment: `Num` is the loop variable in your `for` loop, so it will take on the values from 0 through to 9. It will never be negative. You should be testing the number that you read in, but with your code in its current form that's not possible because you immediately add the read-in number to `total`.

Comment: In your loop, `Num < 0` is never `True`

Comment: Thanks for the comments  - could someone modify the code for me - so that I know where to change it - if possible. Thank you